# Получить все данные из таблицы

Tags: jquery

Помогите пожалуйста написать код. Имеется таблица с 3 формами. На основе нее генерируется pdf файл с таблицей.

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-sm order-list">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Товар</th>
            <th>Стоимость</th>
            <th>Кол-во</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <select id="name" name="name" class="custom-select name">
                    <option selected>Выбрать</option>
                </select>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="form-control cost" id="cost" name="cost" placeholder="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" class="form-control qua" id="qua" name="qua" value="1" placeholder="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


var name = $(".name").val();
var cost = $(".cost").val();
var qua = $(".qua").val();

var externalDataRetrievedFromServer = [
    { 'Наименование': name, 'Стоимость': cost, 'Кол-во': qua }
];
```

Переделали форму с динамическим добавлением новых строк в таблицу, т.е. добавляется новый блок TR с таким же содержимым как и в таблице выше.

Необходимо теперь каким-то образом добавить это все в var externalDataRetrievedFromServer, чтобы получилось так:

```
var externalDataRetrievedFromServer = [
    { 'Наименование': name, 'Стоимость': cost, 'Кол-во': qua },
    { 'Наименование': name, 'Стоимость': cost, 'Кол-во': qua },
    { 'Наименование': name, 'Стоимость': cost, 'Кол-во': qua },
];
```

Строк может быть как 1, так и 10,20,100
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю что-то такое?

```
const externalDataRetrievedFromServer = [];
    $('#myTable  tr').each(function (index, element) {
      externalDataRetrievedFromServer.push({ 'Наименование': $(element).find(".name").val(), 'Стоимость': $(element).find(".cost").val(), 'Кол-во': $(element).find(".qua").val()});
    });
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Все получилось!

Comment: Пожалуйста.  Ну только уберите const name, const cost и const qua.  Обновил.